# Optional parameter on urlManager rules

Tags: yii, parameters, yii-url-manager

I used the `Yii::app()->request->getParam()` so I can have a friendly url like `/listings/amenities/1`.

I got 3 actions on my controller that get the parameter `$property_id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('property_id')`.

The two actions `amenities` and `meals` are working fine but in the last action `photos`, the var `property_id` got a null value.

I tried removing the second param on the photos rule and everything works. How should I solve this without removing the second param `gallery_id`?

Below is the urlmanager rules:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules'=>array(
                'listings/amenities/<property_id>'=>'listings/amenities',
                'listings/meals/<property_id>'=>'listings/meals',
                'listings/photos/<property_id>/<gallery_id>'=>'listings/photos',
             ),
         ),
```

[EDIT]
I think the solution involves how to properly set the rules for optional parameter to handle request like `listings/photos/1` and `listings/photos/1/2`. Adding the OR symbol does not solve it.

```
'listings/photos/<property_id>/<gallery_id>'=>'listings/photos'
```

Comment: finally figure it out, just need to put separate rules 'listings/photos/<property_id>'=>'listings/photos' and 'listings/photos/<property_id>/<gallery_id>'=>'listings/photos'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried using two rules? Place the longer (more restrictive) rule first:

```
'listings/photos/<property_id:\d+>/<gallery_id:\d+>' => 'listings/photos',
'listings/photos/<property_id:\d+>' => 'listings/photos',
```

In your action, set `galleryId` to `null`:

```
public function actionPhotos($propertyId, $galleryId = null) {
```